# VBA function or sub WITHOUT declare many arrays

Tags: vba

I have to replay some code with different input parameters and I want to create `sub` or `function` to make shorter code **without** declare more than 30 arrays and parameters. Please look at the example below.

```
Sub main()

ReDim a(1 To 18) As Integer
ReDim b(1 To 18) As Integer

'first loop
start_1 = 1
stop_1 = 4
For i = start_1 To stop_1
    b(i) = b(i) + a(i)
Next i

'second loop
start_2 = 2
stop_2 = 6
For i = start_1 To stop_1
    b(i) = b(i) + a(i)
Next i

'third loop
start_3 = 3
stop_3 = 9
For i = start_1 To stop_1
    b(i) = b(i) + a(i)
Next i

End Sub
```

I want to move for loop to new sub or function. Second call looper should use array b() after execute first looper.

```
Sub looper()

For i = start_1 To stop_1
    b(i) = b(i) + a(i)
Next i

End Sub


Sub main()

ReDim a(1 To 18) As Integer
ReDim b(1 To 18) As Integer

'first loop
start_1 = 1
stop_1 = 4

Call looper

'second loop
start_2 = 2
stop_2 = 6

Call looper

'third loop
start_3 = 3
stop_3 = 9

Call looper

End Sub
```

How call looper without declare input parameters like looper a, b, 1, 4 but use them in sub?

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: How call looper without declare input parameters like   `looper a, b, 1, 4 ` but use them in sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited** after OP's further needs

this is the most straightforward way

```
Option Explicit

Sub looper(a() As Integer, b() As Integer, iStart As Integer, iStop As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = iStart To iStop
        b(i) = b(i) + a(i)
    Next i
End Sub


Sub main()
    ReDim a(1 To 18) As Integer
    ReDim b(1 To 18) As Integer

    'first loop
    looper a, b, 1, 4

    'second loop
    looper a, b, 2, 6

    'third loop
    looper a, b, 3, 9
End Sub
```

another possibility is use Module level variables, like follows

```
Option Explicit

'Module Level variable declarations make them "visible" in every Sub or Function inside the same Module you place them in
Dim a(1 To 18) As Integer
Dim b(1 To 18) As Integer
Dim iStart As Integer, iStop As Integer

Sub looper()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = iStart To iStop
        b(i) = b(i) + a(i)
    Next i
End Sub


Sub main()
    'first loop
    iStart = 1: iStop = 4
    looper

    'second loop
    iStart = 2: iStop = 6
    looper

    'third loop
    iStart = 3: iStop = 9
    looper
End Sub
```

---

should you need to ReDim your arrays the go like follows (for the Module level variables approach):

```
Option Explicit
'these are Module Level variable declarations so they are "seen" in every Sub/Function inside the same Module you place them in
Dim a() As Integer '<~~ declare array as of variable dimensions
Dim b() As Integer '<~~ declare array as of variable dimensions
Dim iStart As Integer, iStop As Integer

Sub looper()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = iStart To iStop
        b(i) = b(i) + a(i)
    Next i
End Sub


Sub main()
    ReDim a(1 To 18) As Integer '<~~ redim array
    ReDim b(1 To 18) As Integer '<~~ redim array
    'first loop
    iStart = 1: iStop = 4
    looper

    'second loop
    iStart = 2: iStop = 6
    looper

    'third loop
    iStart = 3: iStop = 9
    looper
End Sub
```

Comment: OK, but what if I don't know size of arrays in module level? Size of arrays is counting before first loop.

Comment: @JakupMedon did you get through it?